# Python multiprocessing.Pool not fully using available resources

Tags: python, multiprocessing, slurm

I run a parallel task using multiprocessing.Pool:

```
    with Pool() as p:
    result = sum(tqdm(p.imap(_bin_chunk, zip(load_list, repeat(bins))),
                       total=len(load_list), disable=not verbose))
```

The hardware i run the process on has 80 CPU, and this is correctly reported by `os.cpu_count()`. Using `htop` to monitor the system reveals that of the created 80 processes, only about 30 are actually running, while the others are sleeping.

I thought this might be due to other resources being exhausted (such as memory) but it does not seem to be the case. Does anyone have an idea of what could be going on? Or how to troubleshoot the issue?

I'm running this on a single node of slrum cluster, if that is relevant.

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the size of inputs, and speed of `_bin_chunk`, you might be bottlenecked by the main process pickling and sending the inputs to the child processes. Not a lot to go on here... If you check cpu time of the main process, I'd bet it's pegged at 100% between pushing inputs, and pulling results.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try to figure out if that's the case!